# the use of Out vs outside

Tags: grammar

I brought my son to the washroom to wash his hands.

He didn't want to get out of the washroom.

> "Get out of here."
>
> "Go out"
>
> "Go outside"

Is the 1st one more command and 2nd and 3rd more politely?

Comment: Outside more often means out of the building rather than out of a room.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide more context. *go out* and *go outside* have metaphorical meanings, so the differences between the phrases will vary by situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the first one sounds harsh, none of the above sound really polite. Also, as Tim said, "go outside" doesn't sound correct.
If you really want to sound polite you should use something like "Would you please/mind...?" or just "please".

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Coreplo is good.

I would say: "Would you please unlock the door?" or "Can you please get out?"

Both are fine, since you are talking to your son, but I would use the first one in a more professional setting since it is more polite.